# Use OVER..PARTITION BY with distinct value

Tags: oracle, group-by, distinct, partition-by

Table `CALENDAR_ORG` has the following column and data

```
BUSINESS DAY - 20150801  20150801   20150801   20150801
UNIT_CODE    - HK        IN         HK         IN
GROUP_NAME   - ANG       ANG        ANG        ANG
```

I would like to use `OVER..PARTION BY` to select max `BUSINESS_DAY` categorised by `UNIT_CODE`

If using `GROUP BY`, it will be

`SELECT MAX(BUSINESS_DAY) AS RUN_DATE FROM CALENDAR_ORG WHERE GROUP_NAME ='ANG' GROUP BY UNIT_CODE;`
return:

`20150801
20150801`

Indeed, I am getting 4 records of `20150801` using below query with `OVER..PARTITION BY`

`SELECT MAX(BUSINESS_DAY) OVER (PARTITION BY UNIT_CODE) AS RUN_DATE FROM CALENDAR_ORG WHERE GROUP_NAME='ANG';`

`20150801
20150801
20150801
20150801`

The expected result should be

`20150801
20150801`

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: I would like  to achieve 2 records return using `OVER..PARTITION BY`. Date return should be categorised by `UNIT_CODE`, not depend on number of row of records.

Comment: Please edit the question - and bung in the desired results

Comment: Edited, with desired results

Comment: `OVER()` will not change the number of rows returned, only a `GROUP BY` will. You can use `DISTINCT MAX(BUSINESS_DAY)`

Comment: @Maheswaran Ravisankar `DISTINCT (MAX(BUSINESS_DAY) OVER (PARTITION BY UNIT_CODE)` ? it will only return 1 row

Comment: Ofcourse add the `UNIT_CODE` to select as well

Comment: I just want  `BUSINESS_DAY` to be selected

Comment: it's ok..i can have both columns selected, but only `BUSINESS_DAY` is used for subsequent action

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved

`SELECT DISTINCT (MAX(BUSINESS_DAY) OVER (PARTITION BY UNIT_CODE)) AS RUN_DATE, UNIT_CODE FROM CALENDAR_ORG 
WHERE SGROUP_NAME='ANG';`